# Show unique full content on front page

Tags: 7, nodes

How do you do this in Drupal 7?  I would like to place the following items that are unique to the home page:

1. A views_slideshow
2. A row of 3 large images
3. Some normal typed content
4. 3 most recent Articles

I could manage this on a normal page, but I'm not sure how to put it on the home (front) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in the [Panels module](http://drupal.org/project/panels).  You can create custom layouts, include views/custom content, and more.

From the project page:

> **An Overview of Panels**
>   The Panels module allows a site administrator to
>   create customized layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag
>   and drop content manager that lets you visually design a layout and
>   place content within that layout. Integration with other systems
>   allows you to create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this,
>   and even override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page so
>   that you can customize the layout of your site with very fine grained
>   permissions.

Comment: Is there a standard way to create a homepage that does not require learning another complex module?  Or is the Drupal way to know a lot of PHP or learn a bunch of powerful Modules?

Comment: Generally, if you don't know PHP, you will have to solve more problems with contributed modules.  You could always create a custom front page template (page--front.tpl.php) but you will need to know PHP for that direction